# Filter first match only using Grok or ruby code

Tags: logstash, elastic-stack

I have a field that contains the following data

```
"REQUEST-941-APPLICATION-ATTACK-XSS, REQUEST-941-APPLICATION-ATTACK-XSS, REQUEST-941-APPLICATION-ATTACK-XSS, REQUEST-942-APPLICATION-ATTACK-SQLI, REQUEST-949-BLOCKING-EVALUATION, RESPONSE-980-CORRELATION
```

And I want to return the first item only ie: (REQUEST-941-APPLICATION-ATTACK-XSS), but when i use this grok filter

```
grok
    {
        match => {"attack_names" => "(?<attack>^[A-Z1-9-]+)"}
        remove_field => ["attack_names"]
    }
```

it return all occurrences

```
"REQUEST-941-APPLICATION-ATTACK-XSS, REQUEST-941-APPLICATION-ATTACK-XSS, REQUEST-941-APPLICATION-ATTACK-XSS, REQUEST-942-APPLICATION-ATTACK-SQLI, REQUEST-949-BLOCKING-EVALUATION, RESPONSE-980-CORRELATION
```

So, I tried this ruby code:

```
ruby 
    {
    code => "
            saveid = event.get('attack_names').split(',')[0]
            event.set('attack',saveid)
            "
    }
```

but this dosen't seem to do anything and the filed isn't added to the data.

So, what I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

If your field literally starts with `"REQUEST` then the ^ that anchors the pattern to the start of the field contents will prevent your pattern matching. It is *always* a [good idea](https://www.elastic.co/blog/do-you-grok-grok) to anchor patterns when possible, since it makes a match failure much faster, and the cost of backtracking when matches fail can make grok patterns very expensive.

You could try

```
 grok { match => { "attack_names" => '^\"(?<attack>[A-Z1-9-]+)' } }
```

You do not need to try to consume any additional characters after the end of the pattern that you match.